# Laplace Transform with translation theorem?

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I solve the following Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{te^{t-5}\mathcal{U}(t-5)\}(s)$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the unit step?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 2):

The integral you use is

$$\begin{align}\int_5^{\infty} dt \: t \, e^{(t-5)} e^{-s t} = \underbrace{e^{-5 s}\int_0^{\infty} dt \: (t+5) e^{-(s-1) t}}_{t+5 \leftarrow t} \end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get a very messy antiderivative, was I supposed to?

Comment: PS thank you for answering and helping me figure this out

Comment: @Becky: no, it should all be simple.  Break up the latter integral into the $t$ piece and the $5$ piece, and the integrals from zero to infinity are very simple.